# How to uninstall zenmap?

Tags: uninstall, make

How can I remove zenmap that I installed using [this method](https://nmap.org/download.html):

```
bzip2 -cd nmap-7.00.tar.bz2 | tar xvf -
cd nmap-7.00
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `make uninstall` may work. It's up to the library's authors to provide that. Most libraries usually have one.

Otherwise, you'll have to manually uninstall it. Running `make -n install` will show the steps that the software would take to install itself. You can then try to manually reverse those steps.

PS: In the future to avoid this type of problems try to use `checkinstall` instead of `make install` whenever possible. It will create and install a `.deb` file that you can then uninstall using your favorite package manager.

Comment: The first option you provided worked successfully. Precious information you added after that. Thank you very much.

Comment: There were times when `make uninstall` wasn't the norm. I have run into a lot of such problems since then.